# "Still did" versus "still do"

Tags: tenses

I understand that "did" is past tense and "do" is present tense, but if you see a video of someone dancing a strange dance online, what is more correct to say:

"I didn't realize people still did this."

or

"I didn't realize people still do this."

The second seems more correct to me but the first sounds more correct.

Comment: Neither sound incorrect to me, but specifically for the reference of watching someone do a strange dance I would say "still did this"

Comment: "Still did this", seems right to me. Even an exchange like this would be right: "Do people still do this?" "Yes." "I didn't realise they did." "Oh yes. They do."

Comment: @katatahito For me it has to be "neither sounds incorrect" in the singular. The way you phrased it sounds a little odd.

Comment: @tchrist you are correct, neither is singular

Comment: @OldBrixtonian The point, to me, is that the tense of the verbs should agree. If you say "I didn't realise that people still do this" then "didn't" is in the past tense and "do" is in the present, there's a mismatch. You certainly wouldn't say "Do people still did this?" which is the opposite case.

Comment: @BoldBen Hmm. I don't think we're disagreeing here :-) I didn't recommend "I didn't realise that people still do this". I favoured the questioner's *first* option: "I didn't realize people still did this." Maybe you misread my comment. I agree: the tenses should agree. Though now I think about it there's no present tense version with the word 'realise', is there? "I don't realise" certainly doesn't work.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian - I guess that could be "I'm not sure people still do/did that."  For "did," the context would have made the time period clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sound fine.  If I concentrate hard, I can find a small difference between the two:  In the past tense, you would sound a hair more critical.  In the present tense, you sound a bit more on the side of curious and open-minded (as long as your tone of voice projects a positive attitude as well).

Comment: It's been years since my tone of voice did that! These days it mostly projects bleak despair.